# Getting error "The Response ended prematurely" while using "HttpClient" and "IHttpClientFactory" in .NetStandard2.0

Tags: c#, .net, httpclient, ihttpclientfactory

I have a .netstandard2.0 class library.This is consuming by a .netframework 4.7.2 web api as DLL. We have tried below **static httpclient** But
I'm getting

> "The Response ended prematurely"

(This is the inner most exception).
Not getting for all request, average 50 in an hour.

```
    public class Helper 
    {
        private static readonly HttpClient _httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler() { AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate })
        {
            Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
        };

        public async Task<string> ProviderCallAsync(string url, string Request, string AccessToken, HttpMethod HttpMethod)
        {
            string ProviderResponse = "";
            try
            {
                if (HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Get)
                {
                    url = url + Request;
                }
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod, url);
                if (HttpMethod != HttpMethod.Get)
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(Request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");
                }
                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AccessToken))
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
                }
                request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                System.Net.ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = delegate (object sender, X509Certificate certificate, X509Chain chain, SslPolicyErrors sslPolicyErrors) { return true; };
                ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls11 | System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls;
                HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.SendAsync(request);

                ProviderResponse = await response?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
            return ProviderResponse;
        }
    }
```

I have also tried with **IhttpClientFactory** like below, I have implemented like this as it is a class library and not don't have Startup.CS.  Got same exception

```
public class Helper 
{
        private static readonly object Instancelock = new object();
        private readonly IHttpClientFactory _httpClientFactory = GetHttpClientFactory();
        private static IServiceProvider serviceProvider { get; set; }

        public static void Initialize()
        {
            if (serviceProvider == null)
            {
                lock (Instancelock)
                {
                    if (serviceProvider == null)
                    {
                        var services = new ServiceCollection();
                        services.AddHttpClient("HttpClient", client =>
                        {
                            client.Timeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                        }).ConfigurePrimaryHttpMessageHandler(() => new HttpClientHandler
                        {
                            AutomaticDecompression = System.Net.DecompressionMethods.GZip | System.Net.DecompressionMethods.Deflate,
                            SslProtocols = System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls12 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls11 | System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols.Tls

                        }).SetHandlerLifetime(TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
                        serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public static IHttpClientFactory GetHttpClientFactory()
        {
            if (serviceProvider == null)
            {
                Initialize();
            }
            return (IHttpClientFactory)serviceProvider.GetServices<IHttpClientFactory>().First();
        }
        public async Task<string> ProviderCallAsync(string url, string Request, string AccessToken, HttpMethod HttpMethod, [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerMemberName] string CallerMemberName = "", [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.CallerFilePath] string CallerFilePath = "")
        {
            string ProviderResponse = "";
            try
            {
                if (HttpMethod == HttpMethod.Get)
                {
                    url = url + Request;
                }
                HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod, url);
                if (HttpMethod != HttpMethod.Get)
                {
                    request.Content = new StringContent(Request, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json-patch+json");
                }

                if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(AccessToken))
                {
                    request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + AccessToken);
                }

                request.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate");
                var httpClient = _httpClientFactory.CreateClient("HttpClient");
                using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead))
                {
                    ProviderResponse = await response?.Content?.ReadAsStringAsync();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

            }
            return ProviderResponse;
        }
    }
```

Comment: After the http response headers have been read, the TCP connection is either being closed deliberately by the server, or some other network error is occurring.

Comment: @JeremyLakeman No issue while I have created HttpClient each time, Also no issue when I have tried  HttpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)HttpRequest.GetResponse();